# ZBarMonotouchBinding Error When Returning Symbol Data

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, runtime-error, zbar

I'm using v2 of the ZBarMonotouchBinding that I downloaded from [here on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/zbar/patches/29).  This version didn't come with a libzbar.a file, so I'm using the libzbar.a file from v1 of the binding (which may be the source of my problem??). After downloading the binding I compiled and added the ZBar.dll reference to my sample app.

For the delegate in my sample app I'm using code I found [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056742/marshalling-a-nsobject-already-within-monotouch-to-a-derived-class-instance).

The sample app has no problem showing the scanner and having it recognize a bar code, but as soon as it does recognize the bar code and wants to return the symbol data to the delegate, I get this exception instead of having it call the FinishedPickingMedia event in the delegate:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[ZBar.ZBarReaderViewController+_ZBarReaderDelegate imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0xe2a130

MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[ZBar.ZBarReaderViewController+_ZBarReaderDelegate imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe2a130
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:43
  at Scanner.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/user/Projects/sample/scanner/Main.cs:16
```

It seems like it's not finding the FinishedPickingMedia event, but since it's borrowed code that was said to be working I don't think it's a coding problem.  Just in case here is the source code I'm using:

Controller:

```
public class ScannerViewController : ZBarReaderViewController
    {
        public ScannerViewController ()
        {
            this.SupportedOrientations = ZBarOrientation.All;
            this.ShowBarcodeTracker = true;
            this.ShowsZBarControls = true;
            this.ReaderDelegate = new zScannerDelegate();
        }

}
```

Delegate:

```
public class zScannerDelegate : ZBarReaderDelegate
    {
        public delegate void ScanResult(string scanstrring);
        public event ScanResult ScannedCode;
        public zScannerDelegate ()
        {
        }
        public override void FinishedPickingMedia (UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
        {

            ZBarSymbolSet result = null;

            string retstr = string.Empty;
            foreach (var sresult in info.Values) {
                if (sresult is ZBarSymbolSet) {
                    result = sresult as ZBarSymbolSet;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (result != null) {
                foreach (var itema in result) {
                    Console.WriteLine (itema.Data);
                    retstr = itema.Data;
                    ScanResult ret = ScannedCode;
                    if (ret != null)
                        ret(retstr);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Could it be the libzar.a file that I had to borrow from v1 of the binding that's causing the problem?  Any idea where I can get an updated verison of the libzar.a file or what I can do to try to get around this error?

I've researched it all day but unfortunately there's not a lot of code samples to reference for ZBar and Monotouch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what's wrong with your code specifically, it looks fine to me.
But the latest version of these bindings (along with a sample app) are now hosted on github at https://github.com/Its-Tyson/MonoTouch.ZBar

The `libzbar.a' is the actual iPhone ZBar SDK library being wrapped. You can get the latest version from http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/ (although it has been on v1.2 for quite a while now, and I believe the version you obtained zipped within the V1 bindings will be exactly the same, so I doubt that is the source of your problems.)